# Cannot use limit() in conjunction with with() on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, propel

Anyone have idea how to use one to many relationship on propel ORM?

I'm running following query to retrieve posts and comments from DB.

```
$con = \Propel::getConnection('MYDB');
$query = Posts::create()
            ->filterByGroup(1)
            ->joinWith('Comments')
            ->paginate(1, 4, $con);
```

Comment: Should you be using "PostsQuery::create()..."

Comment: Why are you accessing the connection ($con)?  You should be able to execute the query without passing the connection.

Comment: @muztheaxe I'm not able to execute the query without passing connection

Comment: From the documentation: $authorPager = AuthorQuery::create()->paginate($page = 1, $maxPerPage = 10);